# error C4996: 'std::_Copy_impl': is it safe to disable it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost, odeint

I'm using [odeint boost](http://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/index.html) for solving differential equations. In visual studio 2010, there is no errors showing up but when I use visual studio 2013, I get this error

`xutility(2132): error C4996: 'std::_Copy_impl': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'`

I've solved the problem by disabling the warning using this `#pragma warning( disable : 4996 )` the sample provided in [odeint](http://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/examples.html) is now working. This is the sample,

```
#pragma warning( disable : 4996 )
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

const double sigma = 10.0;
const double R = 28.0;
const double b = 8.0 / 3.0;

typedef boost::array< double, 3 > state_type;

void lorenz(const state_type &x, state_type &dxdt, double t)
{
    dxdt[0] = sigma * (x[1] - x[0]);
    dxdt[1] = R * x[0] - x[1] - x[0] * x[2];
    dxdt[2] = -b * x[2] + x[0] * x[1];
}

void write_lorenz(const state_type &x, const double t)
{
    cout << t << '\t' << x[0] << '\t' << x[1] << '\t' << x[2] << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    state_type x = { 10.0, 1.0, 1.0 }; // initial conditions
    integrate(lorenz, x, 0.0, 25.0, 0.1, write_lorenz);
}
```

My question is is it safe to disable this warning? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should be safe. We have disabled the same warning in the unit tests of odeint.

Comment: _"We have disabled the same warning"_ doesn't strike me as a very compelling argument why it is safe.

Comment: :) Right, it does not explain why you can disable it. Actually I don't remember what the problem with 4996 is.

Comment: The linked duplicate does :)